# Arellano-Bond estimator in Stata

Tags: dynamic-regression

I have a question about Arellano-Bond model in Stata (xtabond/xtabond2). The slopes I get, are they for levels or differences of values? My model to be estimated has a form of (D is first difference):

DY=a+DX1+DX2+....

So should I use already differentiated variables in my analysis or levels variables to get this? I know A-B first-differiantes everything at first, so if I use already differentiated data, are the slopes for differences of differences? In most examples levels variables are used.

Risto from Finland